# Serialization exception: Attempting to deserialize an empty stream

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, exception, serialization, binaryformatter

I'm making a game and using it as my save/load system, then storing the data in a separate "GameData" script. When I first try to start the game I get the following error:

> Serialization exception: Attempting to deserialize an empty stream.

I tried to check if the length was greater than 0 and tried a try/catch version. Both of them get the same error and it gets stuck in a loop. Perhaps there is a way to check if it's the first time you ever open the game and save first? I'd rather just find a way to make sure the file has data before loading. Or maybe I could then create a data instead of using `null`? Any help would be appreciated.

This is the length version of the script.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.IO;
using System;

public static class SaveSystem
{
    public static void SaveData(PlayerCollision playerCol)
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/player.fun";
        FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);

        GameData data = new GameData(playerCol);

        formatter.Serialize(stream, data);
        stream.Close();
    }

    public static GameData LoadData()
    {
        string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/player.fun";
        if (File.Exists(path) && path.Length > 0)
        {
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
            GameData data = formatter.Deserialize(stream) as GameData;
            stream.Close();
            return data;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("Save file was not found in " + path);
            return null;

        }
    }
}
```

This is the try/catch version of the script.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.IO;
using System;

public static class SaveSystem
{
    public static void SaveData(PlayerCollision playerCol)
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/player.fun";
        FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);

        GameData data = new GameData(playerCol);

        formatter.Serialize(stream, data);
        stream.Close();
    }

    public static GameData LoadData()
    {
        try
        {
            string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/player.fun";
            if (File.Exists(path))
            {
                BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
                GameData data = formatter.Deserialize(stream) as GameData;
                stream.Close();
                return data;
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogError("Save file was not found in " + path);
                return null;
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Error Loading Save " + e);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `path.Length` is not what you want. Check `stream.Length` instead. It seems that your file has 0 bytes.

Comment: Thank you for helping! It got rid of the error. It then started running a loop of the debug.log error message but I managed to fix that by running the save functions under "else{}" instead of just using a "return null". Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm just posting the final solution because so many people fix the errors and don't share and post to help anybody in the future. 
As "Dymaniod" above pointed out that I wanted to use "stream.length" instead of "path.length" because, as "WarmedxMints" also pointed out unity answers, the path will always have a greater length than 0.
I still got a load error loop. The final script that worked is below.
Thanks to both of you who helped!!

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.IO;
using System;

public static class SaveSystem
{



    public static void SaveData(PlayerCollision playerCol)
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/player.fun";
        FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);

        GameData data = new GameData(playerCol);

        formatter.Serialize(stream, data);
        stream.Close();
    }

    public static GameData LoadData(PlayerCollision playerCol)
    {
        string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/player.fun";
        FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
        if (File.Exists(path) && stream.Length > 0)
        {
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            GameData data = formatter.Deserialize(stream) as GameData;
            stream.Close();
            return data;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("Save file was not found in " + path);
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            GameData data = new GameData(playerCol);
            formatter.Serialize(stream, data);
            stream.Close();
            return data;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: since `FileStream` is an `IDisposable` you should use `using(FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create) { ... }` then you don't have to implicitly call `stream.Close`

Comment: Also I would not use `new FileStream` but actually rather [File.Open(path, fileMode, fileAccess, fileShare)](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.io.file.openSystem_IO_File_Open_System_String_System_IO_FileMode_System_IO_FileAccess_System_IO_FileShare_) like e.g. `using (var stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))`